# MySQL users: When localhost changed to %, I cannot login

Tags: mysql, privileges

I am developing an app with MySQL. I have MySQL (XAMPP) running on my PC. All works fine but now I want to let other users from our network to login, but I found out that when I change user property "localhost" to % (any computer) I get access denied even with my own account.
So, in the short, everytime I change "localhost" to "%" (any computer) I get "access denied". When switch back to localhost I can log easily.

What is wrong please?
Thank you

Comment: should be moved to serverfault

Comment: Hard to know based on the information given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, `user@localhost` and `user@%` are two completely different and unrelated users.  You need to grant access to your data (and, if applicable, set a password) for `user@%` *in addition to* granting access for `user@localhost`.  One does not also provide the other.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, I will need to have 2 versions of each user in the case I would need to login from localhost or remote? Also for standard users who never connect from lh I can set only %.